# python run tcpdump in remote server

Tags: python, tcpdump

(My purpose is to run tcpdump from python than exit the python script)
I have to run tcpdump in remote server if i run tcp dump in generic syntax then my python program get stuck, if i run it in background then traces are not getting started just 1kb pcap file is created

```py
ssh_client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("tcpdump -i any -w test.pcap")

# Than pcap starts at remote server but my python program gets stuck
# if i run it with background process than python program doesn't get stuck but there is no packet capture at pcap

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("tcpdump -i any -w test.pcap &")
```

Comment: Are you sure it's "stuck" and not just busy running? Running something in the background over SSH also makes no sense.

Comment: Unless you give it a packet limit with `-c`, `tcpdump` keeps running until you interrupt it.

Comment: tcpdump start running the traces but my python program get stuck, it doesn't exit & if i run it with "&" at the end than traces are not getting capture just pcap file get created with 1kb

Comment: Yes, that's what you said.  As Barmar correctly pointed out, unless you tell it not to, `tcpdump` runs forever, and your script has to wait for it.  So, use the `-c` parameter to tell it to stop after a certain number of packets.  I don't see the point of this, anyway.  Why don't you just login and run the tcpdump yourself?

Comment: Actually i was doing automation in which i have to start and stop tcpdump in a remote server & than downloads the traces, i was able to stop the tcpdump using PID & also download it , i cant stop it with -c as i have to run tcpdump till its required by automation testcase, but i was able to run it using syntax      
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("nohup sudo tcpdump -i any -w test.pcap >/dev/null 2>&1 &")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi below syntax works for me i was able to start the tcpdump  & even pyhon program doesnt get stuck

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("nohup sudo tcpdump -i any -w test.pcap >/dev/null 2>&1 &")
```